# Is possible to rewrite this query using only named scopes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I would love to write this query using named scopes only. The reason is simple, I don't want to change code everywhere when I change the way a `Client` is considered **active** (same for `User` considered **connectable**)

Here is my code

**client.rb**

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user

  scope :actives, -> { where(starting_date: a_date, finishing_date: another_date, enabled: true) }
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client

  scope :connectable, -> { where.not(access_token: nil, instance_url: nil) }
end
```

And here you can find my attempts to write this query:

```
# What I would like to write
User.eager_load(:client).connectable.where("client is in :actives scope")

# Current options
# 1 - (but this violates dry)
User.eager_load(:client).connectable.where(['clients.starting_date = ? AND clients.finishing_date = ? AND clients.enabled = ?', a_date, another_date, true).references(:client)

# 2 - My best attempt so far
User.connectable.where(client_id: Client.actives.pluck(:id))
```

And a link to the [GIST](https://gist.github.com/Fire-Dragon-DoL/21984f8114c9b7661f49) for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is ARel's `merge` method. ([An article on this here.](http://ben.hoskings.net/2012-07-04-arel-merge-a-hidden-gem))

Try this:

```
User.connectable.includes(:client).merge(Client.actives).references(:clients)
```

The `includes(:client)` will introduce the :client relation from User which will make the `.merge(Client...)` scope work. And the `.references` is required by Rails 4+ to explicitly state which table the `includes` statement will be referencing.

Comment: Good, I was trying with `merge` but didn't take into account I had to use includes (or `eager_load` in rails 4) and the new `references` thing. Thanks I'll update my code with this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how good of an idea it is, but as long as you ensure your column names are name spaced properly (ie. you can't have 'foo' in both Client and User without prefixing the table name) then this should work:

User.eager_load(:client).connectable.where(Client.active.where_values.map(&:to_sql).join(" AND "))

There must be a nicer way, but the above works for me:

Course model:

```
scope :valid, -> { enabled.has_country }
scope :has_country, -> { where.not(country_id:nil) }
```

Rails console:

```
> Course.where(Course.valid.where_values.map(&:to_sql).join(" AND ")).to_sql
=> "SELECT \"courses\".* FROM \"courses\"  
    WHERE (\"courses\".\"is_enabled\" = 't' 
    AND \"courses\".\"country_id\" IS NOT NULL)"
```

Comment: Mhhh, this feels too hacky for me